# Transfer values from one dataframe to another

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames. The first looks like this:

```
value <- seq(1, 100, length.out=20)
df1 <- data.frame(id=as.character(1:20), 
                  value=value, 
                  stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I have a second dataframe that looks like this

```
df2 <- data.frame(id=as.character(c(1:5, 21:23)),
                  v2=NA, 
                  stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I need the values transferring from `df1` to `df2`, but only where `df1$id == df2$id`. So the dataframe I need is:

```
df2Needed <- data.frame(id=as.character(c(1:5, 21:23)),
                      v2=c(value[1:5], NA, NA, NA),
                      stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you check `?merge` ?

Comment: why do you make `id` as character? It'll sort the names by character which means `21` will come after `2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1, key="id")
dt2 <- data.table(df2)

dt1[dt2$id, value]

#    id     value
# 1:  1  1.000000
# 2:  2  6.210526
# 3:  3 11.421053
# 4:  4 16.631579
# 5:  5 21.842105
# 6: 21        NA
# 7: 22        NA
# 8: 23        NA
```

or using base `merge` as @TheodoreLytras mentioned under comment:

```
# you don't need to have `v2` column in df2
merge(df2, df1, by="id", all.x=T, sort=F)

#   id v2     value
# 1  1 NA  1.000000
# 2  2 NA  6.210526
# 3  3 NA 11.421053
# 4  4 NA 16.631579
# 5  5 NA 21.842105
# 6 21 NA        NA
# 7 22 NA        NA
# 8 23 NA        NA
```

Comment: many thanks all for excellent help, data.table did the job nicely. Seems like this package well worth exploring!

Comment: @RossAhmed, I think, this `data.table` solution (as agstudy shows), is *not* the most efficient implementation. I'll post a better one in a while. Please check back. I think `match` is much more nicer/simpler/faster for your problem though. You should consider looking at Theodore's answer.

Comment: @Arun `as.data.table` is faster than `data.table`. But normally we only convert once as even `as.data.table` copies the whole object. Class can be charged by reference without a copy using `setattr` if needed.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this using `merge()`:

```
df2Needed <- merge(df2,df1,by="id",all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE)
df2Needed <- df2Needed[,c("id","value")]
colNames(df2Needed) <- c("id","v2")
```

and another (more elegant, I think) using `match()`:

```
df2Needed <- df2
df2Needed$v2 <- df1$value[match(df2$id, df1$id)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `LEFT join sql` with `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT df2.id , df1.value
      FROM df2
      LEFT JOIN df1
      ON df2.id = df1.id')

 id     value
1  1  1.000000
2  2  6.210526
3  3 11.421053
4  4 16.631579
5  5 21.842105
6 21        NA
7 22        NA
8 23        NA
```

**EDIT** add some benchamrking:

The **match** as expected is very fast here. **sqldf** is really slow!

**Test on the OP data**

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ag(),ar.dt(),ar.me(),tl())

Unit: microseconds
     expr       min         lq     median        uq       max
1    ag() 23071.953 23536.1680 24053.8590 26889.023 34256.354
2 ar.dt()  3123.972  3284.5890  3348.1155  3523.333  7740.335
3 ar.me()   950.807  1015.2815  1095.1160  1128.112  6330.243
4    tl()    41.340    45.8915    68.0785    71.112   187.735
```

**Test with big data** 1E6 rows of data.

here how I generate my data:

```
N <- 1e6
df1 <- data.frame(id=as.character(1:N), 
                  value=seq(1, 100), 
                  stringsAsFactors=F)
n2 <- 1000
df2 <- data.frame(id=sample(df1$id,n2),
                  v2=NA, 
                  stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Surprise !! merge is 16 times faster than sqldf and **data.table solution is the slowest one!**

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq    median        uq        max
1    ag() 5678.0580 5865.3063 6034.9151 6214.3664  8084.6294
2 ar.dt() 8373.6083 8612.9496 8867.6164 9104.7913 10423.5247
3 ar.me()  387.4665  451.0071  506.8269  648.3958  1014.3099
4    tl()  174.0375  186.8335  214.0468  252.9383   667.6246
```

Where the function ag, ar.dt,ar.me, tl are defined by :

```
ag <- function(){
require(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT df2.id , df1.value
      FROM df2
      LEFT JOIN df1
      ON df2.id = df1.id')
}


ar.dt <- function(){
  require(data.table)
  dt1 <- data.table(df1, key="id")
  dt2 <- data.table(df2)
  dt1[dt2$id, value]
}

ar.me  <- function(){
 merge(df2, df1, by="id", all.x=T, sort=F)
}

tl <- function(){
  df2Needed <- df2
 df2Needed$v2 <- df1$value[match(df2$id, df1$id)]
}
```

**EDIT 2**

It seems that including the data.table creation in the benchmarking it a little bit `unfair`. To avoid any confusion , I add a new function where I suppose that I have already data.table structures.

```
ar.dtLight <- function(){
  dt1[dt2$id, value]
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ag(),ar.dt(),ar.me(),tl(),ar.dtLight,times=1)

Unit: microseconds
        expr         min          lq      median          uq         max
1       ag() 7247593.591 7247593.591 7247593.591 7247593.591 7247593.591
2    ar.dt() 8543556.967 8543556.967 8543556.967 8543556.967 8543556.967
3 ar.dtLight       1.139       1.139       1.139       1.139       1.139
4    ar.me()  462235.106  462235.106  462235.106  462235.106  462235.106
5       tl()  201988.996  201988.996  201988.996  201988.996  201988.996
```

It seems that the creation of the keys (indexes) is the time consuming. But once the indexes are created `data.table` method is unbeatable.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if `dt1` and `dt2` creation should be included in the benchmark.

Comment: @Arun I assumed that data.table creation is fast. The Op gives a data.frame as input, so the coercion to a data.table is part of the solution.

Comment: I guess, one should run `data.table` without creating keys then. Maybe @MatthewDowle could weigh in? I remember him saying that if there are few variables to filter/subset by, then it doesn't make a difference to create a key and key by key column. So, instead one could use `%in%` to subset and then extract value.

Comment: @Arun I see. To create a data.table "match" solution since `%in%` is `match`.

Comment: @agstudy, pretty much. setting key to key by 1 column doesn't give much performance difference. Imagine if you were to key by 3 or 4 columns (subsetting) and then extracting the value.. Then you'd see the difference, I believe. I remember suggesting a similar key column solution to Andrie's answer and Matthew weighing in to explain this (or so I think :))

Comment: @agstudy The function `data.table()` copies to a new object amongst other checks. So of course it's unfair to include copying the whole object each time. If in doubt, or as good practice anyway, why not both include and exclude?  Also the default for `times` in microbenchmark is 100 (not shown in results here, but significant).

Comment: @TheodoreLytras Most interesting yes, but quite unfair.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, Thanks for your input! The time-consuming part seems to be setting `key` on `dt1`. This can be alleviated by not setting the key and using `match` though. But I was wondering why it takes quite a lot of time to `setkey` on 1e6 columns...

Comment: @MatthewDowle No it is fair. The key part creation it is part of the solution. But I agree That once the keys are created the data.table is unbeatable.

Comment: @agstudy I always suggest reporting the time to key included and excluded. Yes I agree it's fair to include setkey (which doesn't copy). But I was talking about the data.table() call.

Comment: @Arun There are 1e6 columns?!  I missed that. data.table is designed for tall skinny tables, like a database. Not wide ones. For very wide data maye a matrix is more appropriate.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, sorry, 1e6 rows with 2 columns. setting key takes long time.

Comment: @agstudy, I think the "unfair" part was for adding the creation of data.table inside the benchmark (from my comment). However, that doesn't seem to be the time consuming part. In this case, another way to do this is also to set key on dt2 (apart from the completely different solution using `match`).

Comment: @MatthewDowle and Arun I add a new test to the bench-marking.

Comment: @agstudy Getting there. But the difference between data.table(...,key=) and setkey() isn't reflected. It's that difference i'm talking about. I wouldn't mind but your text attributes the long time to setting the key, which isn't correct.  Only a call to setkey() is the time to set the key, and I can't see that timed.

Comment: @agstudy `ar.dtLight` will always be insanely faster than everything else when you don't evaluate it

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another approach to the existing list of excellent answers:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(qdapTools)
> mutate(df2, v2 = id %l% df1)
#  id        v2
#1  1  1.000000
#2  2  6.210526
#3  3 11.421053
#4  4 16.631579
#5  5 21.842105
#6 21        NA
#7 22        NA
#8 23        NA
```