# Pandas move rows from 1 DF to another DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have `df1` read from Excel, then I create an empty `df2` with the same columns.
Now I want to move some rows from `df1` matching some condition to `df2`.
Is there any easy way to do this like `pop()` in `list`, meaning the item can be popped to new list and deleted from the old list.

What I am doing is append these rows to `df2`, then `df1=df1[~condition]` to remove them from `df1`, but I always got annoying warnings:

```
"UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
"DataFrame index.", UserWarning)"
```

I think above warning is due to `"df1=df1[~condition]"`, after comment this the warning disappeared.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310140/transfer-values-from-one-dataframe-to-another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310140/transfer-values-from-one-dataframe-to-another)

Comment: Hi the link you suggested is for R not python

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you do not care about your index (which it appears you do not), then you can do the following:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns)

>>> df1
          A         B         C
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863

cond = df1.A < 1
rows = df1.loc[cond, :]
df2 = df2.append(rows, ignore_index=True)
df1.drop(rows.index, inplace=True)

>>> df1
          A         B         C
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278

>>> df2
          A         B         C
0  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
1  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
2  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
```