# Conditionally replace values in data frame from separate data frame in R

Tags: r

I would like to conditionally replace values in a column (df1$y) of a data frame (df1) with values from another data frame (df2$y). These data frames have a shared ID column (x). df1 has more rows than df2 and has values that are not in df2.

The condition is: if df1$x == df2$x, replace df1$y with df2$y, if there is no match do nothing

Ex:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7), 
                    y = c(100, 100, 50, 50, 75, 75, 75, 50, 100, 25))
> df1
   x   y
1  1 100
2  1 100
3  2  50
4  3  50
5  4  75
6  4  75
7  4  75
8  5  50
9  6 100
10 7  25

> df2 <- data.frame(x = c(2, 4, 6, 7), y = c(25, 100, 75, 100))
> df2
  x   y
1 2  25
2 4 100
3 6  75
4 7 100
```

The desired output is:

```
df1
x   y
1 100
1  25
2  50
3  50
4 100
4 100
4 100
5  50
6  75
7 100
```

This is my first question posted here, and please excuse me if this has been answered in another question.

This question is different from [Transfer values from one dataframe to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310140/transfer-values-from-one-dataframe-to-another) because I am asking how to conditionally replace df1$y values, but keep values where df1.x != df2.x.  In the linked to question, values that do not fit the condition are NA values.  See below for an example using sqldf() based on an answer to the link above.

```
    > sqldf('SELECT df1.x , df2.y
+       FROM df1
+       LEFT JOIN df2
+       ON df2.x = df1.x')
   x   y
1  1  NA
2  1  NA
3  2  25
4  3  NA
5  4 100
6  4 100
7  4 100
8  5  NA
9  6  75
10 7 100
```

Comment: so what are the conditions? why do you replace the second row y-value in df1 with the first row yvalue of df2 when the x value doesn't match?

Comment: I should have made that clear.  The condition is: if df1$x == df2$x, replace df1$y with df2$y, if there is no match do nothing.  I'll edit the main post to add this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the two data frames firstly and then use the **dplyr** package for replacing the elements.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "x", all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(is.na(y.y), y.x, y.y)) %>%
  select(x, y)
```

Comment: That worked great!

Comment: An even faster way that saves you the hassle of creating extra data columns: `df1 <- data.frame(x1=1:4,x2=letters[1:4],rank=c(2,1,1,3),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)       

df2 <- data.frame(x1=2:3,x2=c("zz","qq"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

df1$x2[which(base::match(df1$x1, df2$x1) & df1$rank ==1)]<- df2$x2`  The caveat is to make sure the ordering of observations is the same between the original dataframe and the replacement values